# How create variable Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I need make variable VirtualHost without reload Apache configuration when added domain. Does Apache have a variable `%{???}` that contains only the domain name? Variable `%{???}` must contain only the domain name "*example.com*" or "*example.co.uk*", but not subdomain "*www.example.com*" or "*test.example.co.uk*" as variable `%{HTTP_HOST}`

Variable VirtualHost:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        <If "-f '/var/certificates/%{???}/cert.pem'">
            ServerName %{???}
            ServerAlias *.%{???}
            SSLCertificateFile /var/certificates/%{???}/cert.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/certificates/%{???}/private.pem
            SSLCertificateChainFile /var/certificates/%{???}/chain.pem
            #... other stuff ...
        </If>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:** I try use `UseCanonicalName off` whit variable `%-2.0.%-1.0` for get two last part from host (domain name and TLD)

Variable `%-2.0.%-1.0` for domain whit normal TLD (.com, .net, ...) is OK, but for TLD ".co.uk" is WRONG. No matter, I do not need TLD "co.uk".

```
"example.com" => "example.com" OK
"test.example.com" => "example.com" OK
"example.co.uk" => "co.uk" WRONG
"www.example.co.uk" => "co.uk" WRONG
```

But Apache after restart/reload whit new configuration not start when i use rows whit `<If ...`. Error is "*ServerName not allowed here*". How else can I verify the existence of certificates?

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        UseCanonicalName Off
#       <If "-f '/var/certificates/%-2.0.%-1.0/cert.pem'">
            ServerName %-2.0.%-1.0
            ServerAlias *.%-2.0.%-1.0
            SSLCertificateFile /var/certificates/%-2.0.%-1.0/cert.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/certificates/%-2.0.%-1.0/private.pem
            SSLCertificateChainFile /var/certificates/%-2.0.%-1.0/chain.pem
            #... other stuff ...
#       </If>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're probably looking at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html but I don't think it will work with `SSLCertificateFile` and the like directives

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635535/non-wildcard-certificates-with-dynamic-apache-vhosts